# redhat Undefined reference to system call function

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, redhat

I'm trying to add 4 new system calls to the redhat `linux2.4.18-14` kernel.

I followed the following steps:

1- in `arch/i386/kernel/entry.S` `sys_call_table` i added the following lines at the end:

```
.long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_add_TODO)             /* 243 */
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_read_TODO)            /* 244 */
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_mark_TODO)            /* 245 */
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_delete_TODO)          /* 245 */
```

2-  Updated the `MakeFile`:
    added `sys_todo.o` to `obj-y`

3- added `sys_todo.h` which holds the declaration of the system-call functions to `include/linux`

4- added `sys_todo.c` which has the implmentation of the sys-call functions to folder `kernel` (of course i included `sys_todo.h` in the source).

Example of a sys-call function header:
`int sys_add_TODO(pid_t pid , char* TODO_description, ssize_t description_size);`

i used the following script to compile the kernel:

```
FLAG=$1 
cd /usr/src/linux-2.4.18-14custom
make bzImage

if [ $FLAG = '-m' ] ; then
    make modules
    make modules_install
fi

make install
cd /boot
mkinitrd –f 2.4.18-14custom.img 2.4.18-14custom
#reboot
```

The error i get is:

```
arch/i386/kernel/kernel.o: In function `sys_call_table':
arch/i386/kernel/kernel.o(.data+0x43c): undefined reference to `sys_add_TODO'
arch/i386/kernel/kernel.o(.data+0x440): undefined reference to `sys_read_TODO'
arch/i386/kernel/kernel.o(.data+0x444): undefined reference to `sys_mark_TODO'
arch/i386/kernel/kernel.o(.data+0x448): undefined reference to `sys_delete_TODO'
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 2
```

**How to resolve this?**

Comment: did you include sys_todo.h in entry.S?

Comment: no, why is it necessary?

Comment: also, did you edit include/asm/unistd.h?

Comment: did you mean `linux/unistd`? Not in entry.S (i didn't touch any 'original' lines, but the ones i added)